# How to best place a "Filter" sheet in a webpage?

Tags: web-app, interface, filter, guidelines

Consider the following page screen, that consists all conversations (left side) and the selected conversation display (middle of the screen; chat):

[image]

Now I would like to be able to filter the list of the conversations (that's found on the left) by various options such as "Filter by classes" (there can be many of them), "New messages", "Read but unanswered messages", "Has Video, Has Files?" etc. **But where would be the best place to put this filter sheet?** The filter icon is already placed in at the top of the conversations that would enable the filter page.

I have outlined 4 possible options, however all have both good and bad sides:

[image]

A - Makes sense as it looks/feels like is filtering in the actual inbox. However, it hides the actual inbox, making it a bit unintuitive to see what you're filtering for. Having a checkmark icon to confirm the filter would be a solution.

B - Material guidelines suggest to do it this way, to separate it form the navigation drawer on the left. However, in this chat looking design it looks more as if the Filter is related to the specific conversation, not total inbox.

C - okayish I suppose. We're trying to avoid pop-ups if possible. But maybe it is a viable solution

D - Dropdown list next to the icon. This one's tougher as it can't be too large, but can provide difficulties when more options for filtering arise in the future.

**What would you suggest? Perhaps another way completely?**

Answer (score 1):

The best version for me is "B" the one Material suggests, because you can see the filters and the inbox at the same time. This is specially useful if the filters apply as you select them and you can see the effect on the inbox.

The issue is that it's disconnected from the inbox, it's not clear that you are filtering the inbox, like you said.

So a suggestion would be to place the filters next to the inbox and shrink the chat area when filters are open. You still need to figure out what's the best way to trigger the filters. :)

[image]

Comment: Interesting take on the filter sheet appear on the left side, next to the navigation drawer. Material suggests to not do it this way, What is the logic behind this? Though perhaps another sheet appearing on the right to the inbox would be a solution.